# Netlify: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, netlify

Netlify isn't deploying my site and this is the build log, which isn't very descriptive. What could I be doing wrong?

```
10:45:13 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
10:44:47 PM: Netlify Build  
10:44:47 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:44:47 PM: ​
10:44:47 PM: ❯ Version
10:44:47 PM:   @netlify/build 29.16.3
10:44:47 PM: ​
10:44:47 PM: ❯ Flags
10:44:47 PM:   baseRelDir: true
10:44:47 PM:   buildId: 64b75c152cb4263ec24676f2
10:44:47 PM:   deployId: 64b75c152cb4263ec24676f4
10:44:47 PM: 
10:44:47 PM: ❯ Current directory
10:44:47 PM:   /opt/build/repo
10:44:47 PM: ​
10:44:47 PM: ❯ Config file
10:44:47 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
10:44:47 PM: ​
10:44:47 PM: ❯ Context
10:44:47 PM:   production
10:44:47 PM: ​
10:44:47 PM: Build command from Netlify app  
10:44:47 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:44:47 PM: 

10:44:47 PM: $ npm run build
10:44:48 PM: \> react-to-next@0.1.0 build
10:44:48 PM: \> next build
10:44:48 PM: - info Linting and checking validity of types...
10:44:49 PM: - info Creating an optimized production build...
10:44:55 PM: - info Compiled successfully
10:44:55 PM: - info Collecting page data...
10:45:07 PM: - info Generating static pages (0/6)
10:45:07 PM: - info Generating static pages (1/6)
10:45:07 PM: - info Generating static pages (2/6)
10:45:07 PM: - info Generating static pages (4/6)
10:45:07 PM: - info Generating static pages (6/6)
10:45:08 PM: - info Finalizing page optimization...
10:45:08 PM: Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
10:45:08 PM: ┌ ○ /                                      2.12 kB         111 kB
10:45:08 PM: ├   └ css/bf8d7a80a22b1831.css             1.4 kB
10:45:08 PM: ├   /\_app                                  0 B             109 kB
10:45:08 PM: ├ ○ /404                                   182 B           109 kB
10:45:08 PM: ├ ○ /about                                 253 B           110 kB
10:45:08 PM: ├ ○ /learn-more                            276 B           110 kB
10:45:08 PM: └ ○ /programs                              269 B           110 kB
10:45:08 PM: + First Load JS shared by all              113 kB
10:45:08 PM:   ├ chunks/framework-f9926060a251d613.js   45.2 kB
10:45:08 PM:   ├ chunks/main-ad82b3f16479a685.js        32.9 kB
10:45:08 PM:   ├ chunks/pages/\_app-82e18c9465d69c9e.js  30.4 kB
10:45:08 PM:   ├ chunks/webpack-b8f8d6679aaa5f42.js     755 B
10:45:08 PM:   └ css/12a20634ef986059.css               3.92 kB
10:45:08 PM: ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
10:45:09 PM: ​
10:45:09 PM: (build.command completed in 21.1s)
10:45:09 PM: ​
10:45:13 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
10:45:13 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:45:13 PM: Finished processing build request in 46.603s
```

I tried to set up an environment variable CI with a value of false. It didn't work.

I also tried this method from another post:

This is the procedure I followed to solve the issue and successfully deploy the site.

```
Go to Site Settings.

Site Settings

Select Build & Deploy dropdown from the menu.

Select Continuous Deployment tab from the dropdown.

Under the section Build Settings, Select Edit settings.

Change the build command as CI= npm run build
Click Save.
Build Settings

Then select Environment tab from the dropdown.

Select Edit variables.
As the Key enter CI and, as the value enter false.
Click Save.
Environment Settings

Finally retrying the deploying the site again.
```

It didn't work unfortunately. What should I do? Thank you in advance.